# Kohana websites repositories

Tags: repository, kohana-3

I'm trying to work on Kohana and looking for some code. All I found on github is kohanajobs and wings source codes. I'll be thankful for other repositories or sources with minimal changes in structure and core.

Answer (score 1):

- S7n CMS: [official site](http://www.s7n.de/), [Google code](http://code.google.com/p/s7ncms/) and [Github project](http://github.com/S7N/cms).
- Kohanut: [official site](http://www.kohanut.com/) and [Github project](http://github.com/bluehawk/kohanut).
- Jelly's    [official site](http://jelly.jonathan-geiger.com/): [source on    Github](http://github.com/jonathangeiger/jelly-site).
- Icyleaf's [Alpaca](http://github.com/icyleaf/alpaca) (forum
  engine) and [Cactus](http://github.com/icyleaf/cactus) (microblog)
- Zeelot's Yuriko-cms: [official site](http://yurikocms.com/) and [Github project](http://github.com/Zeelot/yuriko_cms)

other stuff (not tested, but may be useful):

- [bolt CMS](http://github.com/boltcms/bolt)
- [vimofthevine's CMS](http://github.com/vimofthevine/kohana-cms)
- [Vendo](http://github.com/vendo/vendo) (e-commerce)